# Експорт данных из mysql server to csv!

Tags: mysql, csv, импорт

Всем привет!

Установленная система Ubuntu 18.04 desktop на которой локально установленный  LAMP. При помощью команды  `mysql -u root -p` был вход в майскл, дале при помощи команды `create databes` создана база  old, далее при помощи `use old`, source в эту базу импортируется большой файл sql 9 Гб, импорт происходит успешно, далее я хочу из таблицы new_ip, которая содержит следущие поля user_id, log_date, ip, поле ip - binary(16), в этом поле записаные ип адреса, только в бинарном виде! При просмотре записей в таблицы **new_ip select * from ip limit 1,4** (что б не все записи просматривать так как она содержит более 17 млн. записей) все отображается корректно кроме ИП адресов, ИП адреса отображаются какимито крякозябликами, непонятными иероглифами! 
При помощи команды select `inet_ntoa(conv(HEX(ip), 16, 10)) from new_ip limit 1,4;` удается просмотреть записи ип в нормальном читабельном виде (формат 192.168.23.11).

**Необходимо:** экспортировать данные из таблицы new_ip в csv при этом что значения по полю ip отображались корректно, как при использовании команды `select inet_ntoa(conv(HEX(ip), 16, 10)) from new_ip`, что б было в читабельном виде формат (192.168.22.13). Также необходимо удалить повторяющийся значения в таблице new_ip по полю ip, что б были только уникальные значения!
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Отредактируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос и приведите его к читаемому виду. Пользователи не смогут помочь Вам, если они не смогут прочитать вопрос. Также хотелось добавить, что желательно всё таки разные вопросы не задавать в одном посте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для экспорта данных берете свой запрос на просмотр, удаляете часть с `limit`, а дальше дополняете конструкцией для экспорта в csv: `INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/ips.csv', получается что-то типа:

```
select inet_ntoa(conv(HEX(ip), 16, 10)) 
from new_ip
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/ips.csv'
```

Можно еще управлять форматом файла, подробнее смотрите на http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-export-table-to-csv/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а как бить тогда из уникальними значениями? Как мне експортировать сразу же уникальние значение по полю ИП?

Comment: `select DISTINCT inet_ntoa(conv(HEX(ip), 16, 10)) from new_ip INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/ips.csv'`

Comment: @Pin_23, если ответ подходи, то примите его как ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: select DISTINCT
не работает видает ошибку

Comment: да `DISTINCT` должен быть возле `ip`, а не перед всем выражением

Comment: Большое спасибо, все получилось вопрос закрит
Извините если что не так